# How to show the first n number of elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has 50 elements with the same class "fields" which are all display none at the moment

```
<div class="fields" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="fields" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="fields" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="fields" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
...
```

How to I only show the first 3 or whatever number. Plus count them with a count on top like the following example below.

So for example if I needed the first 3 this is what i need the divs to look like

```
<div class="fields">
    <h1>Station 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="fields">
    <h1>Station 2</h1>

</div>
<div class="fields">
    <h1>Station 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="fields" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
...
```

So basically only some the number of divs that I need...I already have the number of elements I need to show in this blur statement in the station_count variable. Also notice i need a span tag with the count..any ideas on how to do this

```
    $("#number_station").blur(function(){
        var station_count = $(this).val();
                    //code goes there
    });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How to I only show the first 3 or whatever number.

```
$('div.fields:lt(3)').show();
```

> Plus count them with a count on top

```
$('div.fields:lt(3)').each(function (index)
{
    $('<h1></h1>', {text: 'Station ' + index}).prependTo(this);
}).show();
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TssUB/**

---

Read the jQuery API docs for basic questions like this:

- [`:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)
- [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)
- [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) (for creating new elements)

Comment: Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.

Answer (score 11):

While the other answers will work, I recently discovered and love the jQuery `slice()` method.

```
$(".fields").slice(0, 3).each(function(index) {
    // Do whatever you want to the first three elements
}
```

Comment: `.slice(0, 4)` will give the first four elements, not three, since its arugments are 0-indexed.

Comment: Note, if jquery is at all smart, then the `:lt(3)` selector will be more efficient than `slice()`.  But `slice()` is more flexible for working with middle sets.

Comment: There is a missing bracket `)` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
    $(".fields").each(function() { 
      //do whatever like count then show/hide

    });
```

you can iterate over the hidden divs. So with a simple variable you can start/stop whenever you need.